# Alternative to Google Charts Timeline

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I've been playing around with the Timeline chart from Google Charts. It's great because it's very easy to use. However, I stumbled upon quite some limitations:

- It's not possible to adjust the height of the bars, or the amount of margin around them.
- I cant format the labels of the hAxis. No fonts can be applied, or textcolor, or font-size. And for some reason, two of the labels are in bold. (see image below)
- It's not possible to add a text column on the right containing an extra set of information (for example, the sum of all hours in this row)
- I can't move the hAxis to be displayed above the graph instead of below
- etc...

Here's a link to the image: [image]

For this reason, I was hoping some of you could introduce me to an alternative tool or api that I can use. It needs to be easy to use, and free/opensource. I've Googled for numerous chart tools, but almost no tools provide this SIMPLE timeline type of chart (note that it's not a Gantt chart, but it looks like one).

Comment: If anyone has a solution to those limitations, please shoot! But I'm sure there must be some good alternatives around....

Answer (score 3):

There are a few Gantt chart Javascript libraries, but none seem to be close to the Google Timelines chart.

The only chart I could find that is similar is [Visavail.js](https://github.com/flrs/visavail). It builds upon [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) and is open source, so you can modify it to your liking. Check out the "Custom Category Data" example. It's a lot like a Google Timelines chart.

For your convenience, I've added a screenshot of the example below:

[image: Screenshot of the "Custom Category Data" example]

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with d3.js, here is a d3js based example: http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173